# SimpleHuman plastic slim trashcan cover won't stay on

Tags: kitchens, trash-can

I've got a SimpleHuman 40 liter plastic slim step can (http://www.simplehuman.com/40-litre-slim-step-can-black-plastic) and the lid will not stay on. When I press the foot pedal the cover pops off. Have examined the cover along with the hinges on the trash can and there does not appear to anything wrong with it. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I havent't seen this before, but I do have a Simple Human kitchen trash can we've had for maybe 8 years. I also had a problem that I recently fixed with Plastic Welder adhesive. Anyway, it would help to see how the lid attaches.

Answer (score 2):

From the reviews of these Simple Human trash cans at Amazon, this seems to be a complaint many have reported. It sounds like a design flaw. How long have you owned it?

> The only positive that I have to say about this trash can is that it
>   looks nice. However, the functionality of it is less than desirable. I
>   have had this trash can for almost a year, and it is literally falling
>   apart. The hinge comes off at least once a day, and has to be snapped
>   back on before it will function properly again.